# Intellij no longer showing "Compare" and "Compare with Local" in VCS tab

Tags: intellij-idea

I have been using the various `compare` options frequently but now they do not appear in any project. Restarting intellij has not resolved the issue.

Has anyone else run into this and discovered a solution?  Note in the following screenshot:

( a ) The `Compare with Local` is not shown

( b ) The git options should come up *immediately* : not in a nested popup.

[image]

**Update** For those who wonder about `Compare with local` wrt VCS (/git):here ya go..[image]

Comment: Can you use git commands (compare) on the files from command line? Also try checkout command on that directory again.

Comment: @halil  I have done many git commits/pushes from command line in the interim : also see my answer below: the IJ `diff with local` *is* working. It is a strange problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Diff with local` seems to provide the same behavior as `Compare with local`.  To access that feature  I had to add keystroke to the Keyamp.

It is *beyond strange* that the above behavior / problems just suddently popped up.  I went ahead and nuked the project and rebuilt it- but no help

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot has all the Compare options in there.
Not sure, but probably you mean the [IDEA-171150](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-171150) issue.

UPD. `Compare with local` is the action of FileHistory, and it is still there, e.g. for Subversion History
[image]

Local changes tab never had this, Git Log and new Git History do not have such now. It is now called Diff with local. 
It is not possible to assign a shortcut for the `Show Diff with local` at the moment, unfortunately. There is a request opened to allow choosing the default behavior: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82019

Comment: ( a ) The `Compare with Local` is not shown  ( b ) The popup should hae all of the Git options in the *first* popup - not requiring a series of clicks to get to it.  I will update the OP to make this clear.

Comment: `Compare with Local` is the action in old File History (of a single file/folder). It does not make sense in the context menu of a file, cause it IS the local version.

Comment: I also checked couple versions back, seems it was not there. To see what has been changed compared to the version in the repository, just use Diff.

Comment: Take a look at the update in the OP: since there were discussion on this "not making sense" then ask JB: but it is there and has been for at least 9 years.